# Loading off screen, Ajaxload

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

**Hi,**

I have a question on how I would go about to show an Ajaxloader .gif until a page is loaded. The trick for me is that;
The page currently is built so that the page loads one time, I have a tab system, so it loads everything, and then go between the divs. Because this site is made so that even users with low bandwidth can enter it, you have to click "Load gallery" for the page to start loading the thumbnails.

So what I'm looking for now is; How do I display a Ajaxload where the gallery is supposed to be, from when a user clicks on the "load gallery" and until all the thumbnails are loaded?

Thanks in advance,
Olsson

Comment: Also have  a look at this topic (Duplicate?) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687767/how-do-i-display-a-jquery-dialog-box-before-the-entire-page-is-loaded

Comment: Also check out this script (which is non-jQuery powered)
http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/progress.htm

Comment: Well, I found that topic that you suggested but from what I undestand, he just wants to wait for the loading. What I mean is during the fetching of another page - it want that div to show loading until that external content is loaded, then hide the loader and display the content.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use jQuery ajax. You can us ajaxStart( callback ) to display the loading .gif  ajaxStop( callback ) again to hide it.

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
  $(this).show();
});
```

Here is [link](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax)

Comment: This way, he'll need to load all content with AJAX, and once the AJAX code is loaded, the images will not be cached, so loading will still not be done for 100%.  
-- it also slows down the loading time as there will be an extre request for the ajax file.